# Is it possible to change an .rtf file to .txt file using some sort of batch script on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, rtf

We have a .rtf file that needs to be downloaded from a Windows machine, but it contains a lot of pictures in it so it is 2 GB. I would like to download just the text from this file, so it would be ideal if there was an automated script that ran each day on the Windows machine that could convert this file from rtf to txt. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Batch is not the correct or even the worst choice in my opinion; it does not support the RTF format on its own, so you'd need third-party tools or write your own RTF parser which is (almost) impossible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [unrtf](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/unrtf.htm).

```
unrtf --text /path/to/rtf
```

Comment: Can't compile unrtf. Getting this error: `configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in config "."/config`

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), sure. PowerShell gives you access to the .NET Framework. You can use [System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) to perform the conversion. Your application (or PowerShell code) need not be a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application.

Here is a [a full example](https://blog.kmsigma.com/2014/10/01/converting-rtf-to-txt-via-powershell/).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your skill level, you can

- Use Office Automation to build a script in Word to load the RTF and
  then save as TXT
- Use .NET to load a copy of Word and then save as TXT
- Use .NET and [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to filter unnecessary information
- Use .NET to load the RTF in Internet Explorer and then Save As