# How convert multiple RTF-file to TXT-file

Tags: powershell, rtf

Looking here:
[Is it possible to change an .rtf file to .txt file using some sort of batch script on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977212/is-it-possible-to-change-an-rtf-file-to-txt-file-using-some-sort-of-batch-scri)
I have saw which possible use POWERSHELL for to do it. Was present a full example for to do it but link don't work.
Who can tell me as i can to solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .NET to do this in powershell very easily by implementing the System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox control, loading the richtextfile into it, then pulling the text version out. This is by far the easiest and quickest way I have found to do this.

My function for doing exactly this is here:  https://github.com/Asnivor/PowerShell-Misc-Functions/blob/master/translate-rtf-to-txt.ps1

To explain this a little more basically:

```
$rtfFile = [System.Io.FileInfo]"path/to/some/rtf/file"
$txtFile = "path/to/the/destination/txt/file"

# Load *.rtf file into a hidden .NET RichTextBox
$rtBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$rtfText = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($rtfFile);
$rtBox.Rtf = $rtfText

# Get plain text version
$plainText = $rtBox.Text;

# Write the plain text out to the destination file
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($txtFile, $plainText)
```

Comment: Running powershell and locating at same directory of the script, typing: translate-rtf-txt -src_file "pathfile\rtf\*.*" return me this:
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (translate-rtf-txt:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
The script don't work as batch?

Comment: It is a function rather than a full script. Easiest way to get up and running is to copy the full contents of the function file into your current powershell script and from your current script call the function (translate-rtf-txt -src_file "c:\path\to\file.rtf")

Comment: Now, don't give me error, but typing for example: PS C:\users\...\rtf> .\translate-rtf-txt -src_file "c:\users\...\rtf\#730220210000-730220210000.rtf" dont make txt-file. Where mistake? Just a doubt, it work too with multiple file using mask *.rtf ?

Comment: I'm still not sure whether you understand the difference between a function and a script. In its current state it will not convert all rtf files using an *.rtf mask. If I have time later (I don't now) I *might* be able to convert the function to a script for you (although dont hold me to that). In the mean time I would read up on powershell scripts and functions and see if you can get anywhere.

Comment: I know about difference from function and script but not analyze the script. Just take it as is. My original question was About multiple files and for this was comed to me this doubt. Ok it work for single file. A cycle for read all file of a directory solve my problem but here not work for single file. I am sure to mistake me, but not find where i mistake.

Comment: If you want to paste the code you have currently got in a new answer here then we can take a look and point you in the right direction.