# How to automate saving a .rtf file as plain text using python?

Tags: python, python-requests, rtf

I am working on a project where I use the requests module to grab store catalogs from various nurseries (with the purpose of searching for matches in a list of my own).

Here is a relevant snippet:

```
HEADERS = {
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "User-Agent": "Chrome/87.0.4280.141"}

def get_text_file_rtf(url,nursery_name,append):

    
    response = requests.get(url = url, headers = HEADERS)
    
    ##I'm writing to an intermediary folder just to check. 


    #Write file in binary mode
    with open('tmp/catalog.rtf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)



    # #Strip embeddings from rtf; store as text string
    with open('tmp/catalog.rtf') as f:
        text = f.read()
        text = rtf_to_text(text,errors="ignore")

    
    text = text.lower()

    
    #Write string to text file 
    if append:

        with open(f"TextFiles/{nursery_name}.txt","a") as f:
            f.write(text)
    else:
        with open(f"TextFiles/{nursery_name}.txt","w") as f:
            f.write(text)  
url = "http://perennialgardens.name/files/documents/bac995c1-0c78-4bbf-ae41-77b7c4edef1d.rtf"

get_text_file_rtf(url,"name",False)
```

This is not working though due to some errors in the rtf_to_text function from the striprtf module. The module is removing text that are italicized for some reason.

**My Question**: Is there a subprocess call I can make or a way to use the win32 client to save the .rtf as a plain text file?

When I save the file using the GUI the output is what I desire.

Comment: What do you  mean by "Write Binary to .rtf"? What is returned from your request url?

Comment: Case of misunderstanding what was going on, I just updated the snippet. An rtf file is returned.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. You may be able to use the subprocess module to call 'unrtf --text /path/to/rtf' per an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977212/is-it-possible-to-change-an-rtf-file-to-txt-file-using-some-sort-of-batch-scri